# python - exec - extracting a value

Tags: python, exec

I'm trying to extract some information from a long string that looks like "text". I am interested in extracting a value of "shade":

```
>>> text = 'colors = {\r\n\r\n    "1234": {\r\n        "shade": [1, 2, 3]},   "23": {"shade": [3,4,5]}\r\n}\r\n'
>>> exec(text)
>>> print(colors['1234']['shade'])
[1, 2, 3]
>>> print(colors['23']['shade'])
[3, 4, 5]
```

For now, I always need to specify a key ("1234" or "23"). Is there a way to extract all "shade" values without knowing the key? The output could look like this:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[3, 4, 5]
```

I use "exec", but any other method that works will be fine. I was searching for the answer, but I couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While iterating through the keys of dictionary, check whether it has inner dictionary with the key of `shade` or not. You could do it either using `for` loop or list comprehension:

```
# First solution
>>> for key in colors.keys():
    if colors[key].get('shade', False):
        print(colors[key]['shade'])

        
[1, 2, 3]
[3, 4, 5]
```

---

```
# Second solution
>>> res = [colors[key]['shade'] for key in colors.keys() if colors[key].get('shade', False)]
>>> res
[[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]]
```